# SQL Query to Join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a `order` table like this

```
id  | bookId | bookAuthorId
--------------------------
1      3         2      
2      2         1        
3      1         2
```

and another table

```
bookId  |  book
---------------
  1       bookA
  2       bookB
  3       bookC
```

and

```
bookAuthorId  |  author
------------------------
  1              authorA
  2              authorB
```

I want to get record from `order` table where `id = 1` with result-set like this

```
id | book | author
```

what i  tried :

```
select * from order 
join bookId,bookAuthorId 
   on order.bookId = books.bookId 
       and order.authorId = authors.authorId
```

I don't know how to join these table to get the desired result.How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `where` clause

```
select 
    id, book, author 
from 
    `order`, book, author 
where 
    `order`.bookId = book.bookId 
    and 
    `order`.authorId = author.authorId
```

---

Or

```
select 
    o.id, b.book, a.author
from 
    `order` o 
natural join
    book b
natural join
    author a
```

Comment: -1 for showing the implicit joins which are a SQL Antipattern. We should NOT ever teach people to use this very poor form of SQL.

Comment: One should know all, and one should learn why is one better than another

Comment: One should not learn implicit joins as a beginner. You have no business even knowing they exist until you understand joins.

Answer (score 3):

```
select o.id, b.book, a.author
from 'order' o
join book b on o.bookid=b.bookid
join author a on o.bookauthorid=a.bookauthorid 
where o.id=1
```

Comment: Other than aliases, this is the same answer as GrailsGuy.  Only his would actually work since `other` is escaped.

Answer (score 2):

```
select `order`.id, book.book, author.author
from `order`
join book on (`order`.bookId = book.bookId)
join author on (author.bookAuthorId = book.bookId)
where `order`.id = 1;
```

Assuming that bookAuthorId can be linked to bookId, otherwise you'll need to add a foreign key.

Comment: `order` is keyword in SQL.  You need to escape it.